# What is the recommend way to ask a new question which is an off shoot of a previously asked question

Tags: discussion

I've already asked a question which has received some attention (comments and an answer)
[initial question](https://serverfault.com/questions/411493/my-sql-consuming-as-much-as-60-cpu-time-on-start)

I have another question which while related to my initial question has  a different focus.
The initial question is about MySQL's cpu consumption on an Ec2-micro instance,this new question is about loading times of the WordPress site based on the MySQL installation

What do I do?Do I just edit the first question to include it or start an entirely different question?

Comment: Stack Exchange also has a Wordpress site, so consider whether your second question might be more appropriate here or over there, depending mainly on whether you see this as a server issue or a Wordpress specific issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The previous question and answer set looks fairly complete. If that response acceptably answers the question you had there, you should mark it as the correct/accepted answer, then ask a new question.

It's a good idea to reference the old question, and note how the two are different.

Comment: That second one is important. We frequently get flags on such elaboration questions citing them as duplicates of the original.

Answer (score 12):

Once you have defined the scope of a question, it is *incredibly* poor form to change that scope.  It makes the existing answers look non-sensical or incomplete, and almost always makes it impossible to provide a single canonical answer that addresses all of the points provided.

Just ask a new question.  They're free!

Comment: +1 I've seen good answers to an original question get downvoted because they are no longer a good fit for an edited version of the question. That's not fair on anybody.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers I've been burned by that before too. Happens a lot on SE sites with heavy question editing by high-rep users.

Comment: @smcg, editing that changes the question's meaning is generally done by the posters themselves, not high rep members.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers actually it does happen on RPG.SE a fair amount. I've complained about it and was just told to deal with it.

Comment: Good to see SF isn't the only site dominated by cranky curmudgeons.  <grin>